# Popup on a ImageOverlay On Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I can get a image to overlay and display just fine, but can't seem to get a popup on hover or click. Here is my code for version 1.6.0:

```
 <div id="map"></div>
<script>

    var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [40.75, -74.15],
        zoom: 13
    });

    var osmAttrib = 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';

    var osm = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: osmAttrib
    }).addTo(map);

    var cities = new L.LayerGroup([
        L.marker([40.72801, -74.07772]).bindPopup('Jersey City')
    ]);
    cities.addTo(map);

    L.imageOverlay(
        'http://research.ccountync.com/maps/images/yellow.png',
        [[40.712216, -74.22655], [40.773941, -74.12544]], {
        opacity: 1
    }).addTo(map).bindPopup("This is a yellow box");

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the Leaflet docs for `L.imageOverlay` (https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#imageoverlay), you'll see that by default this layer is not interactive (`interactive` option is set to `false`), which means it does not emit mouse events and as a consequence popup cannot be triggered with mouse click.

Simply define your image layer as interactive and popup will appear upon mouse click:

```
L.imageOverlay(
  'http://research.ccountync.com/maps/images/yellow.png',
  [[40.712216, -74.22655], [40.773941, -74.12544]],
  {
    opacity: 1,
    interactive: true
  }
).bindPopup("This is a yellow box").addTo(map);
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you TomazicM.